# How is job name getting assigned in spring batch junit

Tags: spring-boot, junit, spring-batch

I am testing spring batch job in junit.

```
public void testJob() {
    JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep("processFileStep", params2, executionContext);

    JobParameters params3 = new JobParameters(setJobParams());

    jobLauncherTestUtils.launchStep("downloadResultsFile", params3, executionContext);

    Collection<StepExecution> actualStepExecutions = jobExecution.getStepExecutions();

    assertThat(actualStepExecutions.size(), is(1));

    assertThat(jobExecution.getJobInstance().getJobName(), is("TestJob"));// where is it set to TestJob?
}
```

I dont understand how the job name is set to TestJob. ?Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `JobLauncherTestUtils` to launch a step, Spring Batch will create a single-step job of type `SimpleJob` named `TestJob` surrounding your step and launch it. You can see this in the code [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-test/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/test/StepRunner.java#L136).

This does not seem to be documented, so I created [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/3825) to improve the docs in that regard.

Comment: Thank you Mahmoud