# Set job name in Spring Batch Test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin, spring-batch-tasklet

I am working on Spring Batch Unit test and every time I run my test-case I am getting job name as "TestJob". Is it possible to set/alter this and provide a new job name?

I tried and worked around:

```
jobLauncherTestUtils.setJob()
```

but could find anything helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are launching a single step in isolation. In this case, a surrounding job named "TestJob" is created to wrap the step under test, see [How is job name getting assigned in spring batch junit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65569056/how-is-job-name-getting-assigned-in-spring-batch-junit). It see no obvious way to change it.

But in my opinion, when testing a single step in isolation, the surrounding job name should not really matter.

Comment: Actually I need job name as one of the inputs to the database procedure. I know I can mock dao layer, but wondering how to get actual job name. BTW thank you for the answer. :)